# Monitor goes back to landscape mode after KVM switching to Xubuntu from Windows 11

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-rotation, kvm-switch

my setup is a

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.10"
VERSION="22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)"
VERSION_CODENAME=kinetic
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian

Monitor 1 = Fujitsu P27-9 TS QHD in 2K resolution rotated 90 degrees to the left (portrait orientation)
Monitor 2 = HP X24ih in FullHD resolution (landscape orientation)

The Fujitsu monitor is connected to a Digitus KVM switch 2-Port EAN 4016032466833
via Display Port, the HP monitor is connected to the Fujitsu monitor via Display Port. (daisy chain).

A Microsoft Surface Laptop is connected to the second Display Port of the KVM switch.
When I switch from the Surface Laptop to the Linux computer, the Fujitsu monitor goes back to landscape mode although in the Xubuntu Display Settings I set the mode to "Orientation -> left". Can someone help me preserve the orientation mode on the Fujitsu monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution here in the XFCE forums

https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=15592

Opened "Display" -> "Advanced" and created a profile with the current settings that loads whenever the system detects a screen or multiple screens.
So now when I switch from the Windows machine to the Linux machine with the KVM, the display settings on the Linux machine are correct.